# How to set filter condition on v-select component vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to know whether I can set a condition in v-select so that it shows only the necessary options. Below is an example.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
      <v-layout wrap align-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
          <v-select
            :items="items"
            label="Select an option"
            item-text ="name"
            item-value = "name"
          ></v-select>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        name : 'abc', type : 'test'
      },
      {
        name : 'xyz', type : 'dev'
      },
      {
        name : 'lmn', type : 'test'
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

Here i need to show only the option which are having the type as 'test'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can use [computed properties](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to filter your list and be rendered.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
      <v-layout wrap align-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
          <v-select
            :items="filteredData"
            label="Select an option"
            item-text ="name"
            item-value = "name"
          ></v-select>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        name : 'abc', type : 'test'
      },
      {
        name : 'xyz', type : 'dev'
      },
      {
        name : 'lmn', type : 'test'
      }
    ]
  }),

  computed: {
      filteredData(){
          return this.items.filter(item => item.type === 'test')
      }

  }
})
```

Comment: A word of warning, make sure there is currently bound value included in `filteredData()` otherwise the component is unable to render correclty, e.g. `return this.items.filter(item => item === this.selectedValue || item.type === 'test')`, you probably even want to add `:hide-selected="isCurrentHidden"` as well to hide it afterwards.